# How can i install ONLY LTS version of Jenkins with puppet

Tags: jenkins, puppet

I tried:

```
 # jenkins.pp
        class jenkins {

        yumrepo { "jenkins":
                baseurl  => "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat",
                descr    => "Jenkins",
                enabled  => 1,
                gpgcheck => 1,
                gpgkey   => "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key",
        }
         #package {"jenkins": ensure => latest}
         package {"jenkins": ensure => "1.509.1"} 
      }
      include jenkins
```

But it still installs the latest release, and not the LTS version, which is 1.509.1

Answer (score 0):

You use invalid base url.

Try `http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/`. More Info see: [link](https://github.com/realmedia/puppet-jenkins/blob/master/manifests/repository.pp) and [this](https://github.com/rtyler/puppet-jenkins/pull/38).

Comment: i tried: this is the puppet apply:

ug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderYum: Executing '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install jenkins-1.509.1'
err: /Stage[main]/Jenkins/Package[jenkins]/ensure: change from absent to 1.509.1 failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install jenkins-1.509.1' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do
 at /home/kahmed/qa/puppet_qa/modules/jenkins/manifests/jenkins.pp:12

Comment: i did, so as i was trying out https://puppetlabs.com/blog/module-of-the-week-rtylerjenkins-continuous-integration-server/ and created a jenkins.pp , i tried to do the same with https://github.com/realmedia/puppet-jenkins.git but i get error: 
'/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install jenkins'
err: /Stage[main]/Jenkins/Package[jenkins]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install jenkins' returned 1: 

Error Downloading Packages:
  jenkins-1.514-1.1.noarch: failure: jenkins-1.514-1.1.noarch.rpm from jenkins: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.